# ReactJS canvas drawImage without showing html5 video element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, html5-video

I need to draw the stream from camera on top of a canvas using drawImage, however when I add the video element in react component it shows the element's stream in the page too. If I use display:'none' drawImage can't draw the user's webcam, it draws blank screen. Do I have to show html5 video element in the page or is there a way to play it without showing?

I am getting video stream from camera with getUserMedia:

```
async function getCameraStream() {
      try {
        const constraint = { video: true }
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraint)
        if (videoRef.current) {
          videoRef.current.srcObject = stream
          return
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error opening video camera.', error)
      }
      setLoading(false)
      setCameraError(true)
    }
```

And the video ref is:

```
  return(  <video 
              style={{display: 'none' }}
              ref={videoRef}
              className={classes.sourcePlayback}
              src={sourceUrl}
              hidden={isLoading}
              autoPlay
              playsInline
              controls={false}
              muted
              loop
              onLoadedData={handleVideoLoad}
            />)
```

I am using this videoRef in canvas like:

```
ctx.drawImage(sourcePlayback.htmlElement, 0, 0)
```

Here if the htmlElement is given with display:'none' it doesn't draw. I want to draw the htmlElement but not show it in the page.Is there a way to achieve this? I want html5VideoElement to play invisibly basically.display:none does not work.

EDIT:

Add css as visibility:'hidden' works for this one.

```
sourcePlayback: {
      visibility: 'hidden',
      display: 'flex',
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
```

Comment: I did try to manually hide the video element in this demo https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/ and everything seems to work. Are you sure you only do `display:none` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue in chrome with https://record.a.video.

When I used `display: none` on the video attribute, the video overlay on the canvas was black instead of my camera.

Workaround:

When I set the CSS on the video to `width:1px`, the video shows up on the canvas. I suppose it's *technically* on the screen, but it'll probably work for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, also visibility: 'hidden' does the trick